# Trying to replace the values of a dataframe with the values of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. One has two important labels that have some associated columns for each label. The second one has the same labels and more useful data for those same labels. I'm trying to replace the values in the first with the values of the second for each appropriate label. For example:

```
df = {'a':['x','y','z','t'], 'b':['t','x','y','z'], 'a_1':[1,2,3,4], 'a_2':[4,2,4,1], 'b_1':[1,2,3,4], 'b_2':[4,2,4,2]}
df_2 = {'n':['x','y','z','t'], 'n_1':[1,2,3,4], 'n_2':[1,2,3,4]}
```

I want to replace the values for **n_1** and **n_2** in **a_1** and **a_2** for **a** and **b** that are the same as **n**. So far i tried using the replace and map functions, and they work when I use them like this:

```
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].replace({'a_1':df['a_1']}, df_2['n_1'].loc(df['a'].iloc[0])
```

I can make the substitution for one specific line, but if I try to put that in a for loop and change the numbers I get the error `Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key`. If I take the `iloc`s from there I get the original `df` unchanged and without any error messages. I get the same behavior when I use the map function. The way i tried to do the for loop and the map:

```
for i in df:
    df.iloc[i] = df.iloc[i].replace{'a_1':df['a_1']}, df_2['n_1'].loc(df['a'].iloc[i])
    df.iloc[i] = df.iloc[i].replace{'b_1':df['b_1']}, df_2['n_1'].loc(df['b'].iloc[i])
```

And so on. And for the map function:

```
for i in df:
    df = df.map(df['b_1']}: df_2['n_1'].loc(df['b'].iloc[i])
    df = df.map(df['a_1']}: df_2['n_1'].loc(df['a'].iloc[i])
```

I would like the resulting dataframe to have the same format as the first but with the values of the second, something like this:

```
df = {'a':['x','y','z','t'], 'b':['t','x','y','z'], 'an_1':[1,2,3,4], 'an_2':[1,2,3,4], 'bn_1':[1,2,3,4], 'bn_2':[1,2,3,4]}
```

where **an** and **bn** are the values for **a** and **b** when **n** is equal to **a** or **b** in the second dataframe.

Hope this is comprehensible.

Comment: Can You post third desired dataframe?

Comment: Can you also share the ways you tried to code this with the for loop and with the map function?

Comment: Just edited the original question